# Modify Javascript code from Odoo in custom module in Odoo 11

Tags: javascript, web, inheritance, odoo

I need rewrite this fragment:

```
var _onCarrierUpdateAnswer = function(result) {
var $amount_delivery = $('#order_delivery span.oe_currency_value');
var $amount_untaxed = $('#order_total_untaxed span.oe_currency_value');
var $amount_tax = $('#order_total_taxes span.oe_currency_value');
var $amount_total = $('#order_total span.oe_currency_value');
var $carrier_badge = $('#delivery_carrier input[name="delivery_type"][value=' + result.carrier_id + '] ~ .badge.hidden');
var $compute_badge = $('#delivery_carrier input[name="delivery_type"][value=' + result.carrier_id + '] ~ .o_delivery_compute');
if (result.status === true) {
    $amount_delivery.text(result.new_amount_delivery);
    $amount_untaxed.text(result.new_amount_untaxed);
    $amount_tax.text(result.new_amount_tax);
    $amount_total.text(result.new_amount_total);
    $carrier_badge.children('span').text(result.new_amount_delivery);
    $carrier_badge.removeClass('hidden');
    $compute_badge.addClass('hidden');
    $pay_button.prop('disabled', false);
}
else {
    console.error(result.error_message);
    $compute_badge.text(result.error_message);
    $amount_delivery.text(result.new_amount_delivery);
    $amount_untaxed.text(result.new_amount_untaxed);
    $amount_tax.text(result.new_amount_tax);
    $amount_total.text(result.new_amount_total);
}
};
```

from website_sale_delivery.checkout, in Odoo 11.

How to modify in a custom module this code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? give a hint, and show your own effort first.

Comment: I need change this:
$pay_button.prop('disabled', false);
by:
$pay_button.prop('disabled', true);

The main question is how I can do this change in my custom module. I try with include, extend, etc, by not work.

Comment: edit your question and make it clear.

Comment: @JoSSte, changed

Answer (score 0):

You could get it done by disconnecting the current code execution for the click event and connecting your custom code for the click event handler. Here is a copy/paste modified version of the code based on your suggestion that should work.

```
var _onCarrierUpdateAnswer = function(result) {
    var $amount_delivery = $('#order_delivery span.oe_currency_value');
    var $amount_untaxed = $('#order_total_untaxed span.oe_currency_value');
    var $amount_tax = $('#order_total_taxes span.oe_currency_value');
    var $amount_total = $('#order_total span.oe_currency_value');
    var $carrier_badge = $('#delivery_carrier input[name="delivery_type"][value=' + result.carrier_id + '] ~ .badge.hidden');
    var $compute_badge = $('#delivery_carrier input[name="delivery_type"][value=' + result.carrier_id + '] ~ .o_delivery_compute');
    if (result.status === true) {
        $amount_delivery.text(result.new_amount_delivery);
        $amount_untaxed.text(result.new_amount_untaxed);
        $amount_tax.text(result.new_amount_tax);
        $amount_total.text(result.new_amount_total);
        $carrier_badge.children('span').text(result.new_amount_delivery);
        $carrier_badge.removeClass('hidden');
        $compute_badge.addClass('hidden');
        // your change
        $pay_button.prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
        console.error(result.error_message);
        $compute_badge.text(result.error_message);
    }
};

var _onCarrierClick = function(ev) {
    $pay_button.prop('disabled', true);
    var carrier_id = $(ev.currentTarget).val();
    var values = {'carrier_id': carrier_id};
    ajax.jsonRpc('/shop/update_carrier', 'call', values)
      .then(_onCarrierUpdateAnswer);
};

var $carriers = $("#delivery_carrier input[name='delivery_type']");
$carriers.off('click');
$carriers.click(_onCarrierClick);
```

You will notice the usage of `$carriers.off('click');` to disconnect the Odoo code and the usage of `$carriers.click(_onCarrierClick);` to put the click event handler again running your custom code with the modified version of the original code